# Storing Highcharts in array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

I am plotting a number of highcharts dynamically in a loop and pushing each highchart to an array. So that while clicking on an external button, I can export the charts. But while pushing charts to array, only the last entry is properly set with options.

[image]

i had a reference to a fiddle that suggests to clone the options. `[`https://jsfiddle.net/ndb21y1w/`][2]`

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38574

The fiddle have same series data plotted on all the charts. How to solve this if the data is different for each chart populated. Thanks for any help in advance.

Adding more clarity to question :
The data is populated dynamically in loop. My code logic is like:

```
counter i; 
setInterval(function() {
//logic to populated data...
//It is a multiline chart, so three sets of arrays are populated. 
//filling data1[], data2[] and data3[] .
drawChart(data1, data2, data3);
if(condition true) clearInterval();
i++;
});

drawChart(data1, data2, data3) {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
 title: {
            text: "title",
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1,2,3,4...],
        },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: data1,
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data2,
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data3,
    },
});
chartArray.push(chart);
}
```

This chartArray is where I mentioned to get the last entry only properly.

Comment: at last you want to export data in database column or you such want to be export as file (i.e. pdf,csv,etc)   ? (what option you want)

Comment: Seems like it is issue with `id`. Can you post export chart method also.

Comment: @ShantanuSharma to export as a single pdf.

Comment: I found that if we are using the same container only, this issue occurs after cloning the options. Is there anyway the same container can be reused for all charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a chart you have to pass an HTML element that will be a chart container. In your code that what's missing. Check the demo I have prepared to reproduce this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c60y1t2v/

Code:

```
var chartArray = [],
  counter = 1,
  dataArr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ],
  containers = document.getElementById('containers');

function drawChart(data) {
  var cnt = document.createElement('div'),
    cntId = 'container' + counter++,
    chart;

  cnt.setAttribute('id', cntId);
  containers.appendChild(cnt);

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(cntId, {
    title: {
      text: "title",
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
    }]
  });

  return chart;
}

dataArr.forEach(function(data) {
  var chart = drawChart(data);

  chartArray.push(chart);
});
```

Comment: All the chart options are not included in code here, so i didnt mention about the renderTo container option. Anyway my requirement is to show some graphs in the same container in a regular interval of 3 secs.

Comment: When a new chart is created in the same container the old one is destroyed. It could be the issue.

Comment: yes, of course, so I thought of plotting in different overlapping containers. Can you suggest any other standard way of doing things.

Comment: And what was the result of plotting charts in different overlapping containers? Do you have different or the same options for each chart? Could you reproduce the your issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define options each time you use a new chart. Reinitialize the OriginalOptions every time you create a new chart.

```
const options = [...Array(5)].map(() => {
  const originalOptions = {
    series: [{
      data: [], // some random data
      type: 'column'
    }]
  }
  return Object.assign(originalOptions)
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b2zckrw/)

**Updated:**

For dynamically repopulating the chart, you have to initialize an empty chart and then add new series + redraw whenever your data is populated.

Your redraw function will look something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var data = [];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',{
    series: []
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
i++;
data[i] = [i*10 + 1, i*10+2, i*10+3];
drawChart(data[i]);
if(i > 2) clearInterval(interval);

},1000);

function drawChart(data) {
var series = {
type: 'line',
data: data
}
chart.addSeries(series, false);
chart.redraw();
}
```

[**See Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yfg2bszx/)

Comment: The data is populated dynamically in an interval.

Comment: Do you want to show chart when all data are populated or when each set is populated?

Comment: when each set is populated in regular intervals. Please see the updated code included.

Comment: So in this case, you need to redraw the chart. See updated answer

Comment: So here which is the array that stores the charts? And also there is only one chart populated

Comment: The chart is not stored, its repopulated with the updated data. And as for multiline chart, you need to add multiple series, not charts. There is one chart with three different datasets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202143/discussion-between-mahssuss-moon-and-lekshmi-suresh).

Answer (score 0):

Store chart options in `Array` then map over to Initialize Highchart for each options.

```js
var chartArray = [];

function drawChart(data1, data2, data3, i) {
// Create container for charts
const el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(el).setAttribute("id", "container"+i);

// Create charts
var chart = new Highcharts.chart(el, {
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: data1,
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data2,
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data3,
  }]
});
chartArray.push(chart);
console.log(chartArray);
}

var counter = 0;
var delayTime = 2000;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  var data1 = [30, 70, 50];
  var data2 = [40, 70, 60];
  var data3 = [10, 90, 20];
  drawChart(data1, data2, data3, counter);
  if(counter == 2){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  counter++;
},delayTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway the same container can be reused for all charts. like Highcharts.chart('my-graph-area',o)

Comment: Do you want multiple charts in one container? With intervals timing.

Comment: Even now, it is to the same container chart is loaded, so that while storing into array, it is not properly obtained. Plotting in different container overlapping each of it is a workaround. Can you suggest a better solution

Comment: I have edited above snippet. Charts plotting in different containers and storing into `chartArray`. Check console to get `chartArray` value.

Comment: If it's not working here. Put this `JS` code in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndb21y1w/) and check.

Answer (score 0):

To Print **HTML** as **PDF** you can use this software "**wkhtmltopdf**"

in Linux you need to use this command :

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

There are many library based on "wkhtmltopdf" in many languages so you can use it.

---

Library for PHP : https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf